# Книги по Free Pascal

Tags: pascal, книги

Есть какие-то книги по Free Pascal? Если есть, подскажите какие-нибудь.

Comment: http://www.freepascal.ru/article/book/

Comment: кто-то проголосовал за переоткрытие. вместо этого лучше бы было дополнить описание метки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/freepascal/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Именно по Free Pascal книг немного (я знаю 2, в которых описано про Free Pascal и среду Lazarus). Большинство книг по Паскалю ориентированы на Turbo Pascal, поэтому учебный материал, Free Pascal и Lazarus ищите на сайте, что в комментарии. Если всё же Вам нужны книги, то посмотрите эти:

1. Алексеев Е.Р., Чеснокова О.В., Кучер Т.В. - Самоучитель по программрованию на Free Pascal и Lazarus.
2. Мансуров К.Т. - Основы программирования в среде Lazarus.

Среда Lazarus использует компилятор Free Pascal, так что, если найдетё ещё какую-то литературу по ней - не ошибётесь. Если Вы просто собираетель научиться программировать на Паскале, то и с Turbo Pascal-я тоже можно начать (то, что написано в нём Free Pascal тоже должен откомпилировать).

Книги по Turbo Pascal:

1. Фаронов В.В. - Turbo Pascal.
2. Немнюгин С.А. - Turbo Pascal.
3. Рапаков Г.Г., Ржеуцкая С.Ю. - Программирование на языке Pascal.
4. Виталий Потопахин - Turbo Pascal решение сложных задач.
5. Ян Гордон - Тонкости программирования на языке Паскаль.
6. Окулов С.М. - Программрование в алгоритмах.

Некоторые из этих книг есть [здесь.](http://progbook.net/pascal/page/3/)